# conversion failed when converting date and or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using sql server 2012 and I have a DOB column in my table and the type is nvarchar(50),I used date data type before i changed into nvarchar. I am accepting date of birth by using three combo box(month,date,year) I have attached the code. Please look into it and help me out. Thanks

```
string dob = cmbDate.Text + "/" +cmbMonth.Text + "/"+cmbYear.Text;

query= "Insert into Admissions(
                Admission_date,
                Student_name,
                Father_name,
                Mother_name,
                DOB,
                Gender,
                Address,
                State, 
                City,
                Pincode,
                Admission_for,
                Previous_school,Fees
                )
                values
                ('"+txtAdmDate.Text+"','"+
                txtStudentName.Text +"','"+
                txtFatherName.Text +"','"+
                txtMotherName.Text +"','"+
                dob+"','"+
                gender+"','"+ 
                txtAddress.Text +"','"+
                txtState.Text +"','"+
                txtCity+"','"+
                txtPincode.Text +"','"+
                cmbClass.Text+"','"+
                txtPreviousSchool.Text +"','"+
                txtFees.Text +"')";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Learn to use parameterized queries, providing parameters with the correct types.  Voila!  The problem is solved.

Comment: add this before query= ... >> `dob  = ''' + dob  + '''`

Comment: i want to use ad hoc query. Please tell me why do i get this error.

Comment: You should construct your dates as yyyy-mm-dd or even yyyymmdd.

Comment: **Never ever** concatenate strings with user input to create sql statements! **Always** use parameters! Unless, of course, you want to be exposed to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion..@ Zohar Peled

Answer (score 0):

Use `CreateParameter()` method to put your parameters in your query.
Parameters are strong-typed so you will avoid problems with wrong casts.

Reference:
[CreateParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.createparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)
[SqlParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)
[IDataParameterCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.idataparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var myParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
// Add values, type, direction, etc...
cmd.Parameters.Add(myParam);
```